# How can I arrange objects in my platform as I can see in the image?

Tags: lightning

[image]

I would like to know how can I do the same as the image shown (objetcs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it was the old layout and is now not supported or removed.

Please refer the documentation: [`FAQ - Lightning Experience Navigation Changing with Winter ‘17`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=FAQ-Lightning-Experience-Navigation-Changing-with-Winter-17&type=1), also quoting the relevant information form link:

> In the improved navigation model, the existing vertical navigation menu on the left side of Lightning Experience becomes a horizontal navigation bar at the top of the page